# 403 error in Chrome when attempting to authenticate Cloud Run developer

Tags: google-cloud-run

**Background:**

I've got a project in Cloud Run with two services, both mapped to custom domains.  The production site is `mysite.com` and the development site is `dev.mysite.com`.  I deployed the development site with the `--no-allow-unauthenticated` flag to prevent public viewing.  I want developers to be able to view the site in a browser though.  Based on what I've read the "[solution](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/developers)" Google currently has isn't great.  You have to run the command `gcloud auth print-identity-token` to identify your Bearer token then use the [ModHeader](https://modheader.com/) browser extension to modify the request header.  The token is constantly changing and having ModHeader enabled to change the request header breaks authentication on other pages, so it is big PITA, but it works, mostly.

**Question:**

What doesn't work is having the development site load images from the Google Cloud Storage Bucket.  Every resource which should be pulled from the bucket results in a 403 error for that resource, but the page loads fine otherwise.  I'm the project owner (i.e. my email address is the "owner") and have admin rights on everything including the bucket in question.  The bucket's Access Control is set to "Fine-grained: Object-level ACLs".  When I deploy the project using the `--allow-unauthenticated` the images are accessible.  Why isn't the bucket honoring my token?

**Update:**

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the issue might be related to the fact that ModHeader applies its rules to ALL open tabs.  I tried another header modification extension named [Requestly](https://requestly.io/) which allows rules to be targeted to specific URLs and now my development site is loading images as expected.

Comment: Implement Google OAuth in your application and you will not need plugins.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the plugins, but I'm not real excited about that solution. My production app doesn't require it so that would introduce difference between the production app and dev app. It would be great if the Google Cloud Run dev team would make a browser plugin to handle this.

Comment: If you think it is a valid feature request to Google Cloud Run dev team to make a browser plugin to handle this, you can raise a [Public feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues).

Comment: A browser plugin is not the correct approach. I would not install one. Google Cloud Run implements OAuth for authorization. It is your responsibility to implement authorization in your app if required. Most frameworks support authorization or have add-ons that do.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding.  Won't the OAuth approach require conditional modification of my application based on dev or prod deployment?  That is a non-starter because it makes the dev site a less accurate representation of the prod site.  The additional code maintenance alone (i.e. peppering `@login` annotations throughout the code) for an app that otherwise does not require auth should be enough to deter most from that approach. Is there some way to use the OAuth approach that doesn't require that? Additionally, why do the official docs recommend the plugin approach for browser access?

Comment: 1) I have no idea how your application is written, but I do not pepper my code with anything. I have one route handler that conditionally checks if authorization is required. If yes, redirect the user to an authorization page. 3) If you can argue against adapting an app to support authorization, do you also skip integrating automated tests into your code? 2) Can you provide links that recommend plugins?

Comment: 1) Each view in Django has to know if auth is required or not, typically with an annotation, hence the "peppering" statement.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator.  3) The purpose of a dev site is to mimic the prod site exactly as possible. If we change the way the dev site works just to make the dev site work, its purpose is nullified. This has zero to do with automated testing (which I do).  2) The link to the docs with the recommendation is in my OP. Again for convenience: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/developers

Comment: You are now getting into opinions, instead of a fact-based question that can be answered with facts or citations. I understand the dilemma that you face. If you turn on authorization, then you need to implement authorization. Arguing that point is futile.

Comment: Here is a suggestion. Use a proxy web server that adds the Authorization header to all requests. There are several written in Python and Node.js on the Internet. Your browser then connects to localhost, the proxy forwards requests to Cloud Run.

Comment: Yeah, a proxy server is a good idea.